Adding equations of motion
Consider an object of (constant) mass $m$ subject to forces $F_i$ where $i=1,\ldots,n$. Now assume $s_i, v_i, a_i$ are the corresponding equations of motion (position $s$, velocity $v$, acceleration $a$) resulting only from force $F_i$. If $F_\text{net} = \sum_i F_i$ then from superposition of forces we clearly have:
$$
a_\text{net} = F_\text{net} / m = \sum_i F_i / m = \sum_i a_i
$$
My question is: Does this extend to the net velocity and position, i.e. does $s_\text{net} = \sum_i s_i$ and $v_\text{net} = \sum_i v_i$ hold? If so, how can we show this mathematically, and are there cases where an exception has to be made?

This is only true because mass $m$ is a scalar quantity and derivatives and integrals are linear operators. But with rotational, mass moment of inertia is not a scalar quantity (it is a tensor) and thus cannot extend this reasoning to rotations.

With $\frac{dv}{dt}=a$, we would have
$$
v_{\rm net} = \int a_{\rm net}\,dt = \int\left(\sum_i a_i\right) dt.
$$
Given that we can switch the integral and summation (discussed in this post), you would then have
$$
v_{\rm net} = \sum_i\int a_i\,dt = \sum_i v_i.
$$
The same goes for $s_{\rm net}$.
